# python regex match line containing numbers after string with digit at end

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I capture text in a file with regex, but the string contains a digit in error. I capture without it but when attempting to capture the following line, it returns only the string and not the next line. I am able to capture it when there is no erroneous trailing digit.

I've tried many combinations of regex but yet to succeed.

text:

```
sentences
company_name: company, ltd6

numbers 99 and letters 99 (I want to match anything here and nothing after)
numbers 99 and letters 99 (I don't want to match anything here or after)
```

code that successfully captures the regex but with the number:

```
company_name = re.findall(r"company_name:\s(.*)\D.+", text)
```

code that successfully captures the regex without the number:

```
company_name = re.findall(r"company_name:\s(.*)(?=.\D.+)", text)
```

attempt to capture the following line:

```
next_line = re.findall(r"company_name:\s(.*)(?=.\D.+).*", text)
```

I expect to capture the next line but do not.

Comment: Web sites like this one https://regex101.com/ can help you figure out what is going on with regex.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the next line only, and ignore subsequent lines:

```
next_line = re.sub(r".*company_name:[^\n]+\n*([^\n]+).*", r'\1', text, flags=re.S)
```

ie: `numbers 99 and letters 99 (I want to match anything here and nothing after)`

Comment: thanks this successfully gets that next line and also what is under that; I should have mentioned there are many lines under. Have been trying to keep only up to the next line, but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: I've made a minor modification so it gets the first line and not the subsequent lines

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original expression, I'm guessing that maybe this expression,

```
.*company_name:\s*(.*\D)\s*(\w.*)
```

might work. We have two groups, `(.*\D)` and `(\w.*)`, where our desired outputs are captured.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/mfhPwK/1/)

Or maybe this one:

```
.*company_name:\s*(.*)\s*(\w.*)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NOq6fz/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r".*company_name:\s*(.*\D)\s*(\w.*)"

test_str = ("sentences\n"
    "company_name: company, ltd6\n\n"
    "numbers 99 and letters 99 (I want to match anything here)")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```